# Writing and reading a file for parsing after the download

Tags: java, android, xml, file

Ok, I thought this would be simpler but I was probably wrong..
My parser works fine (directly with the connection works) so I've some BASIC problems with writing and reading a file on Android (aka Java) or with Input/Output Stream..
The problem is that I don't know what's not working.. I'm missing any permission? I'm missing something while writing or reading the file?

Here is the code:

```
            URL url = new URL(urlXml);

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader reader = sp.getXMLReader();

            CustomXmlHandler handler = new CustomXmlHandler();
            reader.setContentHandler((ContentHandler) handler);


            String fileName = getFileName();
            File f = getFileStreamPath(fileName);

            if(!f.exists()) {
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);                  
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();             
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len = 0;
                while((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                fos.close();
                in.close();
            }
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(fileName);
            reader.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(fis)));
            fis.close();
            myObject = handler.getMyObject();
```

Thanks in advance.. I'm getting crazy..

Comment: What sort of output are you getting?  Any error messages, strange results, etc.?

Comment: That's the problem: I'm not getting anything "weird" or exception.. I'm getting myObject empty.. (it's a Collection)

Comment: OMG. I find out the error. I'm an idiot. This code actually works. I was "filtering" out some of my objects for testing porpouse and actually, when I changed the code, I was filtering everything.. Should I keep the code (just if somebody need it) or should I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this code it's fine. The error was somewhere else.

I'll leave the code here for someone else that is looking for something similar!

If I shouldn't just tell me and I'll remove it. :)